# XCode SCM with Subversion - not getting new files

Tags: svn, xcode

I have a subversion server and repository setup and it seems to be working in the basic capacity, but whenever I add a new file to the project from one devstation I am not seeing that file on any other devstations. I have looked all over for documentation on how to really use SCM in XCODE - must say apples documentation is purely about setting it up and is terrible.

Single existing file changes seem to be ok but I am trying to work on a substantial project with files being added all the time. We have multiple people working on the project and that was the purpose of implementing Subversion.

What I am looking for is what process should I be following within XCODE each time I sit down to begin working on the project again? I seem to be missing files that my associates are adding and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know XCode, but your problem is well known:

When you add new files, older svn clients added those files with the wrong depth. To get those files, you have to do an update on the parent folder and specify the depth parameter

```
svn update parentfolder -depth=infinity
```

Comment: Is this something that can be set in a config to happen each time? 
if so do you know what the setting would be?

Comment: Just don't use an svn client version 1.6.0 til 1.6.1 (i.e. use a client linked with 1.6.2 or greater).